# Spaces getting removed while using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup to parse some html, however I keep getting these problems:

```
html = """ <p><b>Influenza</b>, commonly known as "the <b>flu</b>", is an <a href="/wiki/Infectious_disease" title="Infectious disease" class="mw-redirect">infectious disease</a> of <a href="/wiki/Bird" title="Bird">birds</a> and <a href="/wiki/Mammal" title="Mammal">mammals</a> caused by <a href="/wiki/RNA_virus" title="RNA virus">RNA viruses</a> of the family <a href="/wiki/Orthomyxoviridae" title="Orthomyxoviridae">Orthomyxoviridae</a>, the <a href="/wiki/Orthomyxoviridae#Types_of_influenza_virus" title="Orthomyxoviridae">influenza viruses</a>. The most common <a href="/wiki/Symptom" title="Symptom">symptoms</a> are <a href="/wiki/Chills" title="Chills">chills</a>, <a href="/wiki/Fever" title="Fever">fever</a>, <a href="/wiki/Rhinorrhea" title="Rhinorrhea">runny nose</a>, <a href="/wiki/Sore_throat" title="Sore throat">sore throat</a>, <a href="/wiki/Myalgia" title="Myalgia">muscle pains</a>, <a href="/wiki/Headache" title="Headache">headache</a> (often severe), <a href="/wiki/Cough" title="Cough">coughing</a>, weakness/<a href="/wiki/Fatigue_(medical)" title="Fatigue (medical)">fatigue</a> and <a href="/wiki/Malaise" title="Malaise">general discomfort</a>. Although it is often confused with other <a href="/wiki/Influenza-like_illness" title="Influenza-like illness">influenza-like illnesses</a>, especially the <a href="/wiki/Common_cold" title="Common cold">common cold</a>, influenza is a more severe disease caused by a different type of virus.<sup id="cite_ref-Eccles_1-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-Eccles-1"><span>[</span>1<span>]</span></a></sup> Influenza may produce <a href="/wiki/Nausea" title="Nausea">nausea</a> and <a href="/wiki/Vomiting" title="Vomiting">vomiting</a>, particularly in children,<sup id="cite_ref-Merck_2-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-Merck-2"><span>[</span>2<span>]</span></a></sup> but these symptoms are more common in the unrelated <a href="/wiki/Gastroenteritis" title="Gastroenteritis">gastroenteritis</a>, which is sometimes inaccurately referred to as "stomach flu" or "24-hour flu".<sup id="cite_ref-3" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-3"><span>[</span>3<span>]</span></a></sup></p>"""
```

As html is in the soup class, so I print the text with `html.text`

I get this:

```
Influenza, commonly known as "theflu", is aninfectious diseaseofbirdsandmammalscaused byRNA virusesof the familyOrthomyxoviridae, theinfluenza viruses. The most commonsymptomsarechills,fever,runny nose,sore throat,muscle pains,headache(often severe),coughing, weakness/fatigueandgeneral discomfort. Although it is often confused with otherinfluenza-like illnesses, especially thecommon cold, influenza is a more severe disease caused by a different type of virus.[1]Influenza may producenauseaandvomiting, particularly in children,[2]but these symptoms are more common in the unrelatedgastroenteritis, which is sometimes inaccurately referred to as "stomach flu" or "24-hour flu".[3]
```

As you can see, many of the spaces get removed. Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the difference between 3rd and 4th `BeautifulSoup` versions:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BeautifulSoup4
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BeautifulSoup3
>>> BeautifulSoup4(html).text
u'Influenza, commonly known as "the flu", is an infectious disease of birds and mammals caused by RNA viruses of the family Orthomyxoviridae, the influenza viruses. The most common symptoms are chills, fever, runny nose, sore throat, muscle pains, headache (often severe), coughing, weakness/fatigue and general discomfort. Although it is often confused with other influenza-like illnesses, especially the common cold, influenza is a more severe disease caused by a different type of virus.[1] Influenza may produce nausea and vomiting, particularly in children,[2] but these symptoms are more common in the unrelated gastroenteritis, which is sometimes inaccurately referred to as "stomach flu" or "24-hour flu".[3]'
>>> BeautifulSoup3(html).text
u'Influenza, commonly known as "theflu", is aninfectious diseaseofbirdsandmammalscaused byRNA virusesof the familyOrthomyxoviridae, theinfluenza viruses. The most commonsymptomsarechills,fever,runny nose,sore throat,muscle pains,headache(often severe),coughing, weakness/fatigueandgeneral discomfort. Although it is often confused with otherinfluenza-like illnesses, especially thecommon cold, influenza is a more severe disease caused by a different type of virus.[1]Influenza may producenauseaandvomiting, particularly in children,[2]but these symptoms are more common in the unrelatedgastroenteritis, which is sometimes inaccurately referred to as "stomach flu" or "24-hour flu".[3]'
```

So, one way to resolve it is to swtich to [bs4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

> Beautiful Soup 3 is no longer being
>   developed, and that Beautiful Soup 4 is recommended for all new
>   projects.